# How to use not equalto in Groovy in this case

Tags: groovy

I just want to print files which are not located in ss

```
def folder = "./test-data"
//  println "reading files from directory '$folder'"
    def basedir = new File(folder)
basedir.traverse {
if (it.isFile()) {
        def rec = it
    //  println it
                     def ss = rec.toString().substring(12)
if(!allRecords contains(ss)) {
            println ss
            }
        }
```

Comment: What does `allRecords` contain?

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't exactly clear, but it looks like you're just trying to do

```
if (!allRecords.contains(ss)) {
     println ss
}
```

in the last part of your code segment.